# Enabling SSO across several domains that consume the same service based backend

Tags: python, django, cookies, single-sign-on, cross-domain

The most obvious solution here will allow session based authentication which is considered a bad practice in Django REST Framework somehow.

So I have worked out a simple way to play the token in a cookie and then try to read it from the cookie if it is absent in the headers (like in the case of moving between 2 different domains that consume our API).

The request returns the following data in the 'Cookies' sections under 'Network'[image]

However, under 'Application' I cannot see the cookie at all
[image]

This is the code I have written

`middleware.py`

```py
class WhiteLabelSessionMiddleware(MiddlewareMixin):
    def process_request(self, request):
        request_token = request.META.get('HTTP_AUTHORIZATION')
        cookie_token = request.COOKIES.get(settings.WHITE_LABEL_COOKIE_NAME)

        if cookie_token:
            print(cookie_token)

        if cookie_token and not request_token:
            # must be assigned by reference
            request.request.META['HTTP_AUTHORIZATION'] = cookie_token

    def process_response(self, request, response):
        request_token = request.META.get('HTTP_AUTHORIZATION')
        cookie_token = request.COOKIES.get(settings.WHITE_LABEL_COOKIE_NAME)

        if not cookie_token and request_token:
            response.set_cookie(settings.WHITE_LABEL_COOKIE_NAME,
                                request_token,
                                max_age=settings.SESSION_COOKIE_AGE,
                                expires=settings.SESSION_COOKIE_AGE,
                                domain=settings.SESSION_COOKIE_DOMAIN,
                                secure=settings.SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE)

        return response
```

`settings.py`

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware',
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'session_security.middleware.SessionSecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'core.middleware.WhiteLabelSessionMiddleware',
    'core.middleware.TimezoneMiddleware',
    'core.middleware.LastSeenMiddleware',
    'social_django.middleware.SocialAuthExceptionMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django_otp.middleware.OTPMiddleware',
    'referrals.middleware.ReferralMiddleWare',
    'audit_log.middleware.UserLoggingMiddleware',
    'axes.middleware.AxesMiddleware',
]

WHITE_LABEL_COOKIE_NAME = 'nex_token'
SESSION_COOKIE_AGE = 60 * 60 * 24 * 30 * 12
_COOKIE_EXPIRES = datetime.datetime.utcnow() + \
                  datetime.timedelta(seconds=SESSION_COOKIE_AGE)
SESSION_COOKIE_EXPIRES = \
    datetime.datetime.strftime(_COOKIE_EXPIRES,
                               "%a, %d-%b-%Y %H:%M:%S GMT")
SESSION_COOKIE_DOMAIN = '.n.exchange'
SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE = True
SESSION_ENGINE = 'django.contrib.sessions.backends.cached_db'
```

`settings_dev.py`

```
SESSION_COOKIE_DOMAIN = 'localhost'
SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE = False
WHITE_LABEL_COOKIE_NAME = 'nex_token_dev'
```

Am I missing something here?

Comment: Cookies are tied to the domain from which they are set. There is no way of sharing them between different domains

Comment: The setting domain is always api.n.exchange as both dragondex.com.au and thegbdex.com consume it (api.n.exchange). hence api.n.exchange should be able to access it's cookies regardless of which domain is running the client, right?

Comment: Plus on localhost it is the same host, just different ports (according to RFC spec ports do not isolate cookies)

Comment: Can you see if `SESSION_COOKIE_DOMAIN= None` or `SESSION_COOKIE_DOMAIN=  "127.0.0.1"` helps in any way?

Comment: up until now I have tried `SESSION_COOKIE_DOMAIN = 'localhost'` and SESSION_COOKIE_DOMAIN = '.localhost' previously it was `None`. will try `127.0.0.1` however I doubt it'll work as I access localhost via `http://localhost:8000`